# How should I express a mutually recursive data type with constrant in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am not quite clear myself, so if my description is also not clear enough, please let me know.

So, I have two classes:

```
class Prop1 a b | a -> b
class Prop2 c d | c -> d
```

and a data type:

```
data X y z
```

the relations between them are:

1. `X` is a container of `z`, with `y` as an auxiliary container.
2. container `y` shall contain another set of instances `X y z`.
3. `y` satisfies `Prop1`, that is, following holds:

   `instance Prop1 y (X y z)`
4. `X` itself satisfies `Prop2`, therefore:

   `instance Prop2 (X y z) z`

so when I define the instance of `X`, I feel myself in a mess, I wrote something like:

```
instance Prop1 y (X y z) => Prop2 (X y z) z
```

but GHC doesn't seem to be happy with that and asks me to add `FlexibleContexts` and `UndecidableInstances`, which don't make me feel safe.

and I read that it's not good to put constraint on `data`, but i tried and it didn't help:

```
data Prop1 y (X y z) => X y z
```

How should I deal with it in Haskell?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand everything yet. For example, you say "container `y` shall contain another set of instances `X y z`", but how do you plan to ensure that? Why do you want to restrict `Prop2 (X y z) z` instances in the way you suggest? (It looks nonsensical to me -- in fact, `instance Prop1 y (X y z)` already looks nonsensical.) In short: what are you actually trying to do? I appreciate a good abstract question as much as the next guy; but this one smells a lot like an X/Y problem, so I encourage you to include as many practical/motivational details as you feel comfortable including.

Comment: @DanielWagner i am exploring data structure bootstrapping in haskell. that's how the type should be defined in theory. i am pretty much sure it's not an xy problem, since that's the problem i encountered during implementation.

Comment: "Y is the problem I encountered during implementation of X" is pretty much the definition of how an X/Y problem arises -- all that's needed to fit the bill is to avoid talking about X entirely, as you did in this question. Do include details about what data structure bootstrapping is, what it's for, and what you're trying to do with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UndecidableInstances` is safe to use, it just means the compiler doesn't know that it will be able to terminate type-checking/resolving constraints. The worst possible outcome of `UndecidableInstances` is that the compiler fails to terminate. We can see that the compiler terminates by completing an example program.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

class Prop1 a b | a -> b
class Prop2 c d | c -> d

data X y z = X

instance Prop1 y (X y z) => Prop2 (X y z) z

-- An example Y and checking Prop2
data Y = Y

instance Prop1 Y (X Y ())

main :: Prop2 (X Y ()) () => IO ()
main = print "checked"
```

We have to choose a concrete type for `z` for `Prop1 Y x` instances; essentially `y` is determining `z`. I chose `()` for `Y`; there could be another `Y'` with a different `z`.

#### Type Families

If you don't want to use `UndecidableInstances` you can use `TypeFamilies` instead of `FunctionalDependencies`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

class Prop1 a where
    type B a :: *

class Prop2 c where
    type D c :: *

data X y z = X

instance (Prop1 y, B y ~ (X y z)) => Prop2 (X y z) where
    type D (X y z) = z

-- An example Y and get the compiler to run all the way to requiring FlexibleContexts 
data Y = Y

instance Prop1 Y where
    type B Y = X Y ()

main :: Prop2 (X Y ()) => IO ()
main = print "checked"
```

Comment: it's not i don't want to use. i just don't have clear idea about what that is. specifically, whether it's safe or not.

Comment: and could you explain a little bit more? i don't know how your code works too

Comment: `UndecidableInstances` is safe, it just means the compiler doesn't know that it will be able to terminate type-checking/resolving constraints. The worst possible outcome of `UndecidableInstances` is that the compiler fails to terminate.

Comment: sounds nice. has been added to my list of ok-to-use.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: I approve, though [not everybody soes](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2008/04/08/stop-using-undecidable-instances/).